# Magento2: SearchCriteria OR/AND

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-criteria

```
    use \Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data as CatalogSearch;

    use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList;

    use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

    use \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

    use \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

    use \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder;

    use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;

    /*
     * Motor de busqueda por defecto (Magento)
     */

    class Magento extends Base

    {


    protected $_catalogSearchHelper;

    protected $_filterableAttributeList;

    protected $_productRepository;

    protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

    protected $_filterBuilder;

    protected $_sortOrderBuilder;

    protected $_filterGroupBuilder;


    /**
     * Magento constructor.
     * @param CatalogSearch $catalogSearchHelper
     * @param FilterableAttributeList $filterableAttributeList
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(CatalogSearch $catalogSearchHelper, FilterableAttributeList $filterableAttributeList, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder, FilterBuilder $filterBuilder, FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder){

        $this->_catalogSearchHelper = $catalogSearchHelper;
        $this->_filterableAttributeList = $filterableAttributeList;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->_filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;

    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el nombre del motor de busqueda
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEngineName()
    {
        return "Magento";
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve si es valido el criterio de busqueda
     * @param $searchTerm
     * @param $storeId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValidSearchData($searchTerm, $storeId)
    {

        if (is_null($searchTerm) || strlen($searchTerm) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $helper = $this->_catalogSearchHelper;
        $len = strlen($searchTerm);
        if ($len getMinQueryLength() || $len > $helper->getMaxQueryLength()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    /**
     * @param $storeId
     * @param $searchTerm
     * @param $searchOrder
     * @param $searchDir
     * @param $page
     * @param $pageSize
     * @param $totalSearchResults
     * @param $attrs_applied
     * @param $attrs_available
     * @return array
     */
    public function search($storeId, $searchTerm, $searchOrder, $searchDir, $page, $pageSize, &$totalSearchResults, &$attrs_applied, &$attrs_available)
    {

        $result = array();


        $filter1 = $this->_filterBuilder->setField('name')
            ->setValue('%' . $searchTerm . '%')
            ->setConditionType("like")
            ->create();

        $filter2 = $this->_filterBuilder->setField('description')
            ->setValue('%' . $searchTerm . '%')
            ->setConditionType("like")
            ->create();


        $filterGroup = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter1)->addFilter($filter2)
            ->create();


        $searchDirection = ($searchDir == "DESC") ? SortOrder::SORT_DESC : SortOrder::SORT_ASC;
        //$this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filter1);
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($searchOrder, $searchDirection);
        $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup])->setCurrentPage($page)->setPageSize($pageSize)->create();
        //$searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
        $products = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        $totalSearchResults = $products->getTotalCount();
        $products = $products->getItems();


        //$searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);


        //ids encontrados
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $result[] = $product->getId();
        }


        return $result;
    }

}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder::setFilterGroups()

Answer (score 1):

For **OR** condition check following code.

**DI**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
    ..........
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
    ...........
}
```

And now inside your method:

```
$filter1 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('name')
    ->setValue('%'.$searchTerm.'%')
    ->setConditionType("like")
    ->create();

$filter2 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('description')
    ->setValue('%'.$searchTerm.'%')
    ->setConditionType("like")
    ->create();

$filterGroup = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter1)
    ->addFilter($filter2)
    ->create();
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup])->create();

$products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$totalSearchResults = $products->getTotalCount();
$products = $products->getItems();
```

[More detail](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/)

Comment: Not work: throw Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder::setFilterGroups()

Comment: Which version you tried? It's good with 2.1

Comment: Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/SearchCriteriaBuilder.php#L92

Comment: i am using magento 2.1.7  and my class SearchCriteriaBuilder NOT has that method

Comment: It's works with 2.1.7. Can you check first section of code? ' __construct'?

Comment: public function __construct(
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
        SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($objectFactory);
        $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
    }

Comment: You need to add answer '__construct' param into your class? If you still  confuse, then update your question with complete class.

Comment: i have added all my class code. I dont understand why dont have that function

Answer (score 1):

I had to use

```
$searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
```